# Convert Bitmap to OpenCvSharp IplImage

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm unfortunately struggling with this. I have a project that is mixed with Emgu and OpenCvSharp.  Sounds odd but there are reasons.

At any rate, what I have is an EMGU.CV.Image that I'd like to use to populate an OpenCvSharp IplImage

I'm assuming this is possible, however I cannot wrap my head around it.

Relevant snippet of code (C#):

```
            FrameCapture = Cv.CreateFileCapture(@"C:\test\vid1.mp4");

            var frm = cap.QueryFrame();
            var frameBmp = frm.Bitmap;

            IplImage curFrame = ??? <<====== I'd like to create curFrame based on frameBmp
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are the internal memory layouts of the two classes? Can you fetch raw pixel data?

Comment: thanks ananthonline...I think that's the problem really.  I'm not sure what to try.  Raw pixel data may be the way to go.  I'm looking at the properties available to me on an OpenCvSharp.IplImage object and I'm not sure how I would copy that data over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer is always simple.

For anyone who encounters this problem, the following is what you can do:

```
            var frm = cap.QueryFrame(); // this is an Emgu.CV.Image object
            var frameBmp = frm.Bitmap; // this is the bitmap from that object

            Frame = new IplImage(frameBmp.Width, frameBmp.Height, BitDepth.U8, 3);  //creates the OpenCvSharp IplImage;
            Frame.CopyFrom(frameBmp); // copies the bitmap data to the IplImage
```